# Costs for the Microsoft Azure Translation API 3.0

Tags: azure, translation, multilingual

my question does not concern programming but the cost of the Microsoft Azure Translator API Version 3.0.

Sorry if this is the wrong place for this question, but maybe someone can help me. Unfortunately I could not find any exact information online.

I wonder if you pay per input or per output character count. 
So does the translation from one input language into multiple output languages cost more (i.e. with "&to=de&to=en") than into a single output language? (I use the S1 instance tier.)

Thanks already for the help!

Comment: Hi Daniela, wouldn't you rather send Microsoft a mail or contact their support team for more accurate information?

Comment: I have already tried that, but have not received an answer. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I understand. so I went on the website and this is what I found https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/api-management/ There is also a link at the bottom "Calculator" that can assist you in calculating costs. That could help you. play around with that let me know if it helps. If not let's see where else we can fish that information for you.

Comment: Many thanks and sorry for the late response!
I haven't found this table yet, but it helps me already. As I understand, you pay per unit per hour. Unfortunately I'm not quite sure what exactly a "unit" means. There is an explanation at the bottom of the page, but I think it's not explained very clearly.

Comment: Let me look that up for you

Comment: I posted as an answer below do let me know if it helps and do mark it as an answer if it serves the question right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to find what you need;

**API Management:** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/api-management/

**API Text Translator:** https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/

There is also a link at the bottom "Calculator" that can assist you in calculating costs. That could help you.

Its calculated in units. Units in a simple explanation would mean packages. so each package as of the time I looked it (API Management) up is 2,500 and that means 2,500 requests per second.

I hope this clarifies it better.

Comment: This is the pricing for API management, a completely different service

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/

Answer (score 0):

The pricing is here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/

The link for the calculator is this one:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=cognitive-services

Select 'Translator Text' and a unit.

For the pricing, for most western languages the difference between paying for input vs output would be in the -30% to +30% range.

Comment: I think that this range applies to a translation into one language, right? However, I am interested in the translation into two languages. Thanks anyway for the answer!

Comment: I would have interpreted the statement "€8.433 per million chars of standard translation" that the input character is relevant for the pricing.

Comment: Yes, I think this is per language, I don't think this API can return multiple translated strings in a single call. So for each language the cost will roughly double

Comment: Thank you! (And I meant the output (not input) character count of course. :) )